# Bundler: bundle pack, vendor/cache...

Tags: bundler

According to Bundler (http://bundler.io/v1.3/rationale.html)

> The --deployment flags adds the following defaults:
>
> ...
>
> If you have run `bundle pack`, checked in the `vendor/cache` directory,
>   and do not have any git gems, Bundler will not contact the internet
>   while installing your bundle.

Questions:

1. is `bundle pack` the same as `bundle package`? If not then, as `bundle -h` doesn't show any details about `bundle pack`, how do you find out more about `bundle pack` (other than trawling through Google results!)
2. does "checked in the `vendor/cache`" mean checked into git? And, if so, how does `bundler` know you've checked it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is bundle pack the same as bundle package? If not then, as bundle -h doesn't show any details about bundle pack, how do you find out more about bundle pack (other than trawling through Google results!)

Yes. Both `bundle package` and `bundle pack` accomplish the same. Refer to this line in [`lib/bundler/cli.rb`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb#L517). The `map` command inside a `Thor::CLI` aliases the command(s) given to it as an argument. In this case, it converts "pack" to `:package` which is a recognized task.

---

> does "checked in the vendor/cache" mean checked into git? And, if so, how does bundler know you've checked it in?

Bundler doesn't check if the `vendor/cache` is checked into git repo or not. It only checks if the directory exists and [sets the `--local` flag appropriately](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb#L222) when `bundle install` is run. The last paragraph in [`bundle package` man page](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/man/bundle-package.ronn) gives a subtle reason why there is a need to check-in the vendor/cache directory into source control. Other than that, I couldn't find any code that necessitates checking in the `vendor/cache` directory into source control for the purposes of the `bundle` command.